# Undefined index и offset

Tags: php, ооп

*Имеется следующий код:*

```
  $variants     = $this->variants->get_variants_one(array(
                'product_id' => $products_ids
            ));
            $array_weight = array(
                '0_2' => '0.2',
                '0_5' => '0.5',
                '1_0' => '1.0',
                '2_0' => '2.0',
                '3_0' => '3.0',
                '4_0' => '4.0',
                '5_0' => '5.0',
                '1' => '-1',
                '2' => '-2',
                '3' => '-3',
                '4' => '-4',
                '5' => '-5',
                '6' => '6',
                '7' => '7',
                '8' => '8',
                '9' => '9',
                '10' => '10'
            );
            foreach ($variants as &$variant) {
                $products[$variant->product_id]->variants[] = $variant;
                foreach ($array_weight as $key => $w) {
                    $ctt = $this->variants->count_attachment(array(
                        'variant_id' => $variant->id,
                        'weight' => $w
                    ));
                    $products[$variant->product_id]->count_att[$key] + $ctt;//линия 621
                }
            }
```

Он вызывает следующие 'PHP Notice':

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 0_2 on line 621
```

*Хочется заметить, что на месте 0_2 в notice так же стоят числа с нижним подчеркиванием начиная от 0_2 заканчивая 5_0.*

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 on line 621
```

*Тут вызывается ошибка с числами так же из array_weight, только от 1 до 10.*
Сама линия 621:

```
            $products[$variant->product_id]->count_att[$key] + $ctt;//линия 621
```

Я считаю что именно из-за этих notice скрипт считает некоторые значения неправильно, буду рад услышать ваши предложения, касательно ликвидации последних.

Answer (score 1):

Да у вас в массиве `$array_weight` имеются ключи '0_2' и '0_5', однако, скрипт сообщает, что этих ключей нет в массиве `$products[$variant->product_id]->count_att`. Вероятно объект `$products[$variant->product_id]` не инициализирован должным образом или в принципе не содержит таких величин.

Comment: вообщето он перебирает один массив а использует другой.

Comment: да, я это и имел в виду, что по программе ожидаются ключи из первого массива, а их нет.